# Punish everyone for the action of one

Tags: single-word-requests

Many of us have experienced this as early in life as primary school.

One person in a group does something stupid, and everyone has to pay the price.

**Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example**

> Imagine sitting in Math class in a classroom at school. One kid is
>   acting up, shooting spitballs at people, and so the teacher gives
>   extra homework to the whole class.

Is there a word describing this policy? Punish everyone for the actions of one?

(BTW, not that it matters, but, IMNSHO, this is bad policy. Thx, Keith :^)

Comment: Paste the title of this post into google search box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***[Collective punishment](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/collective-punishment.html)*** is the formal expression:

> - Penalty imposed on every member of a group without regard to his or her involvement in the group's actions and conduct.

([www.businessdictionary.com](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/collective-punishment.html))

Comment: But wait. See my comment at OP.